# How to set text (in label) from the textfield

Tags: java

I'm making a cash register.

I would like to set the text of the label (cost) when the text in the textfield (receipt) is "chocolate".

```
private void dodaj_produktActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
 {                                              
   product_name.getText();
   String str = product_name.getText();
   receipt.setText(str);
   String chocolate="chocolate";

   if(str == chocolate){
       Double cena=3.50;
       String cena_tabliczka = Double.toString(cena);
       cost.setText(cena_tabliczka);
   }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing incorrectly.  In Java you need to use the `.equals()` operator for comparing objects.

Instead of:

```
if(str == chocolate){
```

Try this:

```
if(str.equals(chocolate)){
```

Or if you don't care about case

```
if(str.equalsIgnoreCase(chocolate)){
```